# Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write

Tags: support, app

I have problems with registered Stack Apps, I've tried different combinations, but it doesn't work.

OAuth Domain
9924033ab80e.ngrok.io/

Application Website:
http://9924033ab80e.ngrok.io/

Application Icon (optional):
''

Stack Apps Post (optional):
''

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! You need a registerd Stack Apps post for write access; *this* is one, so you can enter its URL under 'Stack Apps Post (optional)' – that should give you write access.